# Do Not Echo File Operations

Tags: ruby, rake, echo

I have a Ruby script that I'm running in PowerShell (via Rake) which contains a number of operations from `FileUtils`.  (Things like `cp`, `cp_r`, etc.)  It seems that anything within `FileUtils` has its command echoed to the screen when it's executed.  I've looked around but haven't found a way to turn this off.  Is there a way to not echo anything to the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set this in the options hash in FileUtils by specifying :verbose => false

Edit: If you're running rake it has its own FileUtils extension you should be able to do this directly, try adding this to RakeFile..

```
Rake::FileUtilsExt.verbose(false)
```

Comment: From looking at the source, it appears verbose is false by default

Comment: That did the trick, thanks!  (Answer will be accepted as soon as SO's waiting period elapses.)